# Export pandas dataframe as an interaction file: row \t value \t col

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cytoscape

With the below pd dataframe:

```
print(df)
   A  B  C
X  1  2  3
Y  4  5  6
Z  7  8  9
```

I need to create a simple interaction network file, or SIF file, of the format:

```
node1 xx node2
node1 xx node2
node1 yy node2
.
.
.
```

Where each line is an interaction on a df: row label, value, column label.  Below is an iterative (and naive) approach to writing such a file:

```
with open ('interaction.sif', 'w') as sif:
    for row in df.index:
        for col in df.columns:
            sif.write('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(row, df[col][row], col))
```

The inefficient code above offers the ideal sif file for the dataframe `df`:

```
X 1 A
X 2 B
X 3 C
Y 4 A
Y 5 B
Y 6 C
Z 7 A
Z 8 B
Z 9 C
```

Is there a dataframe method to write to a csv or table, for example, in the format above?  Or is there a way to vectorize this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = list('ABC')
df = df[['A','C','B']]
print (df)
   A  C  B
0  X  1  A
1  X  2  B
2  X  3  C
3  Y  4  A
4  Y  5  B
5  Y  6  C
6  Z  7  A
7  Z  8  B
8  Z  9  C
```

And then [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
print (df.to_csv(sep='\t', index=None, header=None))
X       1       A
X       2       B
X       3       C
Y       4       A
Y       5       B
Y       6       C
Z       7       A
Z       8       B
Z       9       C

df.to_csv('interaction.sif', sep='\t', index=None, header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a function you're looking for is [stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
which in pure form will give you the following result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 4, 7], 'B': [2, 5, 8], 'C':[3, 6, 9]}, index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
df.stack()

X  A    1
   B    2
   C    3
Y  A    4
   B    5
   C    6
Z  A    7
   B    8
   C    9
dtype: int64
```

which than can be easily exported to csv using below:

```
df.stack().to_csv('sample_unordered.csv', sep='\t')
```

But so far as order of columns matters for you, this will require a bit more data manipulation:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.loc[:, ['level_0', 0 ,'level_1']].to_csv('sample_ordered.csv', sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

Alternative solution would be using [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt) function:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df.reset_index(1), id_vars=['index'], value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C']).sort_values('index')
df2[['index', 'value', 'variable']].to_csv('sample_melt.csv', sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```